# Is it possible to access SharePoint Server data from Azure service using C#?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, azure

Currently I'm accessing SharePoint server users' My Site section using a C# Console application which I'm executing directly from the server itself with Administrator permissions. I wonder if there is a way to access this data from remote Azure Service? If there is - HOW?

Comment: All that's required is the ability for HTTP/HTTPS web-connections (and client libraries if using the SP Object Model) -- what "doesn't work" now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is using the SharePoint Web Services:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms479390(v=office.12).aspx

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look at the [SharePoint and Windows Azure Development Training Kit](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/steve_fox/archive/2011/08/31/sharepoint-and-windows-azure-developer-training-kit-summer-update.aspx), which was just refreshed about a day ago. [One lab in particular](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/spazuretrainingcourse_sharepointwindowsazureintegration_unit) focuses on 3 methods for integration.